# getter 'classification' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm about two weeks old into flutter and I don't understand what the error really means. I'll add the stack below:

```
List<DropdownMenuItem> showDropdownMenus() {
return CLASSIFICATION.map((item){
  return DropdownMenuItem(
    value: item,
    child: Text(item),
  );
}).toList();
```

}

The error stack:

> I/flutter ( 4403): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building RegistrationPage(dirty, state:
>   I/flutter ( 4403): RegistrationPageState#21643):
>   I/flutter ( 4403): The getter 'classification' was called on null.
>   I/flutter ( 4403): Receiver: null
>   I/flutter ( 4403): Tried calling: classification
>   I/flutter ( 4403):
>   I/flutter ( 4403): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:50:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #1      RegistrationPageState.build (package:lesson2/view/registrationpage.dart:99:44)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4012:27)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3924:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #5      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #6      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4053:11)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #7      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #8      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #9      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #10     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5092:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #11     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #12     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #13     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #14     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #15     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #16     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #17     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #18     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #19     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5092:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #20     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #21     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #22     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5092:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #23     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #24     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #25     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5092:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #26     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #27     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #28     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5092:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #29     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #30     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #31     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #32     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #33     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #34     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4053:11)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #35     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #36     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #37     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #38     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #39     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #40     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #41     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #42     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #43     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #44     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #45     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #46     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #47     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4053:11)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #48     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #49     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #50     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #51     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5092:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #52     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #53     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #54     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #55     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #56     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #57     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #58     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #59     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #60     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5092:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #61     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #62     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #63     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #64     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #65     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #66     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4053:11)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #67     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #68     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #69     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #70     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #71     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #72     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #73     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #74     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #75     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #76     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5092:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #77     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #78     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #79     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #80     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #81     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #82     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #83     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #84     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #85     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #86     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #87     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #88     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4053:11)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #89     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #90     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #91     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #92     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #93     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #94     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #95     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4053:11)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #96     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #97     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #98     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #99     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4875:32)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #100    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5208:17)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #101    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #102    _TheatreElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:607:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #103    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #104    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #105    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #106    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4085:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #107    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #108    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #109    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #110    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4219:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #111    _InheritedNotifierElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:94:11)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #112    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #113    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5099:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #114    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #115    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #116    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #117    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4085:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #118    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #119    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5099:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #120    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #121    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5099:14)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #122    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #123    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #124    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #125    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2340:33)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #126    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:700:20)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #127    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:285:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #128    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1016:15)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #129    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:958:9)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #130    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:874:5)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #134    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:236:10)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): #135    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:194:3)
>   I/flutter ( 4403): (elided 3 frames from package dart:async)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your CLASSIFICATION might not correctly initialized.

please check example below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

List<Map> _jsonApi1 = [
  {"id": 0, "name": "default 1"}
];
List<Map> _jsonApi2 = [
  {"id": 1, "name": "second 2"},
  {"id": 2, "name": "third 3"}
];
List<Map> _myJson = new List.from(_jsonApi1)..addAll(_jsonApi2);

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _mySelection;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 500.0,
              child: new Center(
                child: new DropdownButton<String>(
                  isDense: true,
                  hint: new Text("${_jsonApi1[0]["name"]}"),
                  value: _mySelection,
                  onChanged: (String newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      _mySelection = newValue;
                    });

                    print(_mySelection);
                  },
                  items: _myJson.map((Map map) {
                    return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: map["id"].toString(),
                        child: new Text(
                          map["name"],
                        ),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You were right. I didn't properly initialize it but VS code didn't throw an error either so I didn't know what was wrong with my code. I figured it out. Thanks!